# Is there a word for someone who often takes remarks out of context in a negative manner

Tags: adjectives

My boyfriend often uses sarcasm or speaks in general terms. I have a tendency to take his remarks out of context and respond to them in a negative manner. Is there an adjective to describe this characteristic?

Comment: "Cynical", maybe?  I can't think of any word for "someone who takes things out of context" other than "clueless", but a *cynic* will always choose the more negative interpretation of something.

Comment: It occurs to me that it is the boyfriend that needs characterizing not the girlfriend. I mean what exactly does "take remarks" out of context when a person's tone is sarcastic? When two people are talking, and there's sarcasm, it may very well be directed at the other person even if one believes one is directing it "out there" or elsewhere.

Comment: I would also echo Lambie's concern that you might be in the right.  Not all sarcasm is humorous and not all attempts to be taken sarcastically should be let to slide. I'm on the more forgiving side, but still, if the things he's being funny about all happen to target you, find a new boyfriend.

Answer (score 1):

You have a **"reactive"** temperament.

[**reactive**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reactive) (adj) - "readily responsive to a stimulus, marked by reaction"

Comment: Well, yes, but that is not her context exactly. Even if she didn't take his remarks out of context, your word would still apply.

Comment: @Lambie  What about "precariously reactive"?

Comment: Between you and me, I don't think there is one word here. So many times people want a single word when there is no such beast. I mean, does one go around saying: I'm extrapolative? Actually, I think you and I assumed she was talking about herself...:)